# Cannot login on ASP.NET Identity site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am developing a new ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0 and I'm using ASP.NET Identity for the membership system of the site. However, I cannot log in the user even though my `SignInManager` returns `SignInStatus.Success` after the signin attempt.

Here is my controller code for the login function:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        var user = _db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == model.Email).FirstOrDefault();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        var result = await _signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
            model.Email, model.Password,
            model.RememberMe, false
            );

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login error");
            return View();
        }

        if (user.Role == "Admin")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Users");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Account");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have Identity services and middleware is setup in Startup.cs file.

Ensure you have `app.UseAuthentication` in Configure method. And Cookie based authentication is setup in ConfigureServices method using `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie`

Check [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)

Comment: Thanks, I was missing `app.UseAuthentication`